# Convert this Word DataFrame into Zero One Matrix Format DataFrame in Python Pandas eliminates " "

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

Want to convert user_Id and skills dataFrame matrix into zero one DataFrame matrix format user and their corresponding skills

**Input DataFrame**

```
     user_Id                        skills

 0     user1               "java, hdfs, hadoop"
 1     user2               "python, c++, c"
 2     user3               "hadoop, java, hdfs"
 3     user4               "html, java, php"
 4     user5               "hadoop, php, hdfs"
```

**Desired Output DataFrame**

```
 user_Id       java  c   c++     hadoop  hdfs    python  html    php     

 user1         1     0   0       1       1       0       0       0
 user2         0     1   1       0       0       1       0       0
 user3        1     0   0       1       1       0       0       0
 user4         1     0   0       0       0       0       1       1
 user5         0     0   0       1       1       0       0       1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me works [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) + [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df1 = df['skills'].str.get_dummies(', ')
print (df1)
   c  c++  hadoop  hdfs  html  java  php  python
0  0    0       1     1     0     1    0       0
1  1    1       0     0     0     0    0       1
2  0    0       1     1     0     1    0       0
3  0    0       0     0     1     1    1       0
4  0    0       1     1     0     0    1       0

df = pd.concat([df['user_Id'], df1], axis=1)
print (df)
  user_Id  c  c++  hadoop  hdfs  html  java  php  python
0   user1  0    0       1     1     0     1    0       0
1   user2  1    1       0     0     0     0    0       1
2   user3  0    0       1     1     0     1    0       0
3   user4  0    0       0     0     1     1    1       0
4   user5  0    0       1     1     0     0    1       0
```

EDIT:

If no `space` with `,` use:

```
df1 = df['skills'].str.get_dummies(',')
```